# Extended class of JPanel not showing properties of JPanel

Tags: java, swing, inheritance, panel

I am using a class RefreshablePanel that extends JPanel

```
public class RefreshablePanel extends JPanel {
    static String description="";
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        g.drawString(description, 10, 11);
}
    void updateDescription(String dataToAppend){    
        description = description.concat("\n").concat(dataToAppend);
       }    
}

JPanel descriptionPanel = new JPanel();
scrollPane_2.setViewportView(descriptionPanel);
descriptionPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
descriptionPanel.setLayout(null);
```

[image]

Now when I do it like this

```
RefreshablePanel descriptionPanel = new RefreshablePanel();
scrollPane_2.setViewportView(descriptionPanel);
descriptionPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
descriptionPanel.setLayout(null);
```

[image]

Comment: In the `paintComponent` method, always do call `super.paintComponent(g)`, otherwise the panel drawing will not continue after your custom drawing.

Comment: That custom panel looks like it really should be a standard panel that holds a `JLabel` (possibly with an empty border, for white space) to display the text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this has changed is because when you override `paintComponent`, you must always call `super.paintComponent(g)` as the first line:

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawString(description, 10, 11);
}
```

The `paintComponent` method in the `JPanel` superclass paints the background, so if you insert `super.paintComponent(g)`, the background will be painted before you paint anything custom.

Comment: @BackSlash Oops. Fixed that now.

Comment: Thanx for the answer, that worked and for that extra knowledge along with what I asked for

Answer (score 3):

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawString(description, 10, 11);
}
```

You should always invoke super.paintComponent() when you override the paintComponent() method.